# SvelteKit endpoint handlers inside the /api folder return GET method not allowed

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have been looking for a possible fix for this as I have no clue why this is happening.

I have a really basic login POST function inside the `/api` folder.

```
/src/routes/api/login/+server.ts

import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { RequestHandler } from './$types';

export const POST: RequestHandler = ({ cookies }) => {
    const data = await request.json();

    ...

    return json({ employee: { email: data.email, id: 123 }});
};
```

The problem is that when I do `POST http://localhost:5173/api/login` it returns a 405 error: `GET method not allowed`.

If I move the `/login` folder outside the `/api` folder, and try again the request `POST http://localhost:5173/login` (this time without /api) it works fine.

The request is made from the /auth/+page.svelte file, but I've tried it in Postman and the result is the same.

```
/src/routes/auth/+page.svelte

<script lang="ts">
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

    let email = '';
    let password = '';

    const login = async () => {
        const response = await (
            await fetch('/api/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
        ).json();

        if (response.employee) {
            goto('/');
        } else {
            // Error
            loading = false;
        }
    };
</script>

...
```

Maybe I've missed a configuration...? I have been working with SvelteKit for several months now and this has never ocurred before. I have also not seen any issue or discussion threads related to this, which lead me to believe it is a problem on my end, but have yet to find anything that I could be doing wrong or that could fix this.

Would very much appreciate some suggestions/ideas/fixes and thanks in advance!

Comment: can you include the code where you make the request?

Comment: Sure. I've tried in in postman and the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one?

```
// svelte.config.js

import node from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';

export default {
  kit: {
    adapter: node(),
    paths: {
      // specify a custom route for the login endpoint
      '/login': {
        // path to the server file handling the POST request
        post: 'src/routes/api/login/+server.ts'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi! First of all, thank you so much for the response. When I do this it doesn't let me run the project: error when starting dev server: Error: Unexpected option config.kit.paths./login

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered that the error was totally my bad. I was intercepting the request in the hooks.server.ts file and the request made to `/api/auth` was redirecting to `/login`.

As `locals.employee` didn't exist the request was not displaying the `/api/auth` route, but the `/login` route.

```
// src/hooks.server.ts

import { redirect, type Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    const { locals, cookies } = event;

    if (!locals.employee) {
        locals.employee = await authenticateJwtCookie(cookies);
    }

    if (!event.url.pathname.startsWith('/login')) {
        if (!locals.employee) {
            throw redirect(303, '/login');
        }
    }

    const response = await resolve(event);

    return response;
};
```